# Difference between DeleteJob() and Unschedulejob() in Quartz 1.8.5

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Can someone let me know the difference between deleteJob() and unscheduleJob() of quartz 1.8.5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the implementations of both methods in [QuartzScheduler.java](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/quartz/branches/quartz-1.8.x/quartz/src/main/java/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.java) , you'll notice that deleteJob(JobKey jobKey)

- loops through all the triggers having a reference to this job, to unschedule them
- removes the job from the jobstore

whereas unscheduleJob(TriggerKey triggerKey) just unschedules a trigger, so if other triggers reference this job, they won't be changed.